# Response is not getting in (android socket programming/ tcp/ip socket programming )

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I am developing one Android Application in which I have to send location data on server and getting job data as a response in this way all communication is build but i am stuck of my mind on one thing when i trying to read the response from server the no any output and no any response is coming so please help me out of this stuck. Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

> ```
>    public static class  MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
>         String dstAddress;
>         int dstPort;
>         String response = "";
>         String s;
>         String red;
>         String loc;
>         String msg;
>         Socket socket = null;
>         DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
>        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
>        InputStream is=null;
>        BufferedReader br=null;
>         public MyClientTask(String addr, int port,String msg){
>          dstAddress = addr;
>          dstPort = port;
>          loc=msg;
>         }
>         @Override
>         protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
>
>             try {
>                   socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
>                   socket.setKeepAlive(true);
>                   dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
>                   is=socket.getInputStream();
>                  socket.setSoTimeout(60*1000);
>                   dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(is);
>
>                   Log.i("socket connect","socket OK");
>                   dataOutputStream.writeUTF(loc);
>                   while (dataInputStream == null)
>                     {
>                         ////this part is not working
>                         Log.i("DEV", "sleep "+is.available());
>                         android.os.SystemClock.sleep(100);
>                     }
>                   br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream));
>                   String st = null; 
>                   while(socket.isConnected()){  
>                        st = br.readLine(); 
>                        }
>                   Log.w("server response", "says Server = " + st);
>
>                   Dbase db2=new Dbase(mcontext);
>                    db2.addresponse(new info(st));
>                   Log.w("second time server response", "says 2ndTime Server = " + st);
>               } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
>                   Log.e("at exception", "at thread unknownHost " + e.getMessage());
>                   e.printStackTrace();
>               } catch (IOException e) {
>                   Log.e("io exception", "at thread IO " + e.getMessage());
>                   e.printStackTrace();
>               }
>
>               finally{
>                   Log.i("on finally block", "finally");
>                   if (dataOutputStream != null){
>                       try {
>                           dataOutputStream.close();
>                       } catch (IOException e) {
>                           Log.e("io eception", "at thread dataoutput IO " + e.getMessage());
>                           e.printStackTrace();
>                       }
>                   }
>
>                   if (dataInputStream != null){
>                       try {
>                           dataInputStream.close();
>                       } catch (IOException e) {
>                           Log.e("data input exception", "at thread datainput IO " + e.getMessage());
>                           e.printStackTrace();
>                       }
>                   }
>                   if (socket != null){
>                       try {
>                           Log.i("socket", "socket closed");
>                           socket.close();
>                       } catch (IOException e) {
>                           Log.e("socket exception", "at thread finally IO " + e.getMessage());
>                           e.printStackTrace();
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
>               return null;
>           }
>
>              @Override
>              protected void onPreExecute() {
>                 super.onPreExecute();
>                 //displayProgressBar("Downloading...");
>              }
>
>
>              @Override
>              protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
>                 super.onPostExecute(result);
>              }
>       }
> ```

Comment: Are you obligated to use sockets? I mean, many people have invented the wheel since in many different and easier-to-use ways...

Comment: For location data use web service if possible rather than socket programming.

Comment: yes i have to developed this application using socket have you any idea about my problem you must share with me please..

Comment: @crazy coder sorry i have to implement only socket programming and successfully send location data to server but not getting response by server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use InputStream.available method incorrectly. This method will not try to retrieve data. Actually most implementations of this method always return 0. See [Inputstream available reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available()).
I recommend you just remove available checks and let readLine block as needed. The same goes for BufferedReader.ready - generally this does not show that you will get any data when attempting to read so this call is also not useful.

Comment: sir actually server not sending response on particular time or onrequest that's why need to check the the inputstream availability in this case InputStream.available() is needed..

Comment: InputStream.available cant help you here. In your case it probably always returns 0. If server does not respond a socket timeout will occur. If you want you can change socket timeout value.

Comment: i remove InputStream.available  check condition it also not giving me reponse from server